# populate listView with specific data

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I'm working on an app consists of

- three `Buttons` to enter three different `Fragments`, each of them contains a `List`. when you press on the toggle `Button` next to any `ListItem` it is added to a `SQLite` database.
- `Button` for Summary contains three lists to populate saved data from each `Fragment`.
  My problem is (for example how can I retrieve saved data from `fragment_one` **ONLY** to the `listView_one` in the Summary activity) ?

N.B. all the data are of the same type (from the same model) and the saved ones got saved in the same database.

I've searched and found that I should use `Fragment` tag during `FragmentTransaction`..

What should I do after I set a `tag` for each `Fragment`?
When should I check the `tag` to populate the data correctly?

Sorry for that long question but i'm little overwhelmed and got stuck at this point.

Comment: so the problem is that you need to get only saved data from fragment_one but you dont know how to distinguish it from all  db saved data right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your problem, we have 2 ways to do this:

1. add a `tag column` in your db, then you can retrieve saved value from each fragment with your desired tag.
2. create a singleton manage each fragment saved data, etc:

   > public class DataManager {
   >
   > // singleton implementation
   >
   > ...
   >
   > private List mFragmentOneSavedData; // just save db row id to query later
   >
   > ...
   >
   > }

Thanks.

Comment: For the first way, in my opinions you should create an extra variable in your data java model, etc: `mTag`, and you need to add column `tag` to your data table, then when you save data to db for each fragment: `mTag = frag1` or `frag2` ... whatever you want. Later we can easily retrieve saved data of `frag1` by sql query with `WHERE tag = frag1`.
Note that if you use `ORM` its easier cause we only need to add a field on the data schema.